# Unable to create installdriver instance

Tags: installation, installshield

When trying to install a program called "AV Grabber", I get the following error message.

unable to create installdriver instance

Product name is: EZ Grabber
Right click on the executable 7.1.79.0

I have tried installing Install Sheild 7, but have no luck trying to remove this error message. Any Ideas?

Machine: 
Windows XP (Home Edition)
User Account: Administrator Account

Folder version of installshield is visible from: 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\InstallShield\Driver\7\Intel 32

Have tried the following command, but have not helped.
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\InstallShield\Driver\7\Intel 32\IDriver.exe" -Embedding

Comment: Are you using an admin account to install?

Comment: Yes using admin account for the installation the folder version of installshield is visible from:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\InstallShield\Driver\7\Intel 32

Answer (score 0):

Might want to take a look at [this site](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=Q107052&sliceId=) it is a knowledgebase entry on this issue which seems to crop up a lot.